# What is the interpretation of the expectation notation in the GAN formulation?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, expected-value

I'm confused about the expectation notation in the context of GAN loss functions.

The GAN loss for the discriminator is binary cross-entropy. ie: is this real or not.

real = $D(x)$ (ie: give the discriminator a real image)
fake = $D(G(z))$  (ie: generate a fake image and ask discriminator what it is)

Then the binary crossentropy is:
$$log(p) - log (1-p)$$

When used as a GAN loss we replace p with either "real class" or "fake class".

$$log(real) - log (1-fake)=\\
log(D(x)) - log (1-D(G(z)))$$

So far, this is ok (i think haha).

But the actual formulation adds an expectation sign... which I don't understand why it's there.

$$E_{x~data}log(D(x)) - E_z log (1-D(G(z)))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the fact that $D$ wants to maximize the loss over all potential examples it sees and not just a single example: for real data points, this is done by minimizing the expectation over all true data points of $\log(D(x))$ (your first term). For false points (which are generated by $G$ from the noise distribution $z$), it wants to maximize the expectation over all of these points of $\log(1-D(G(Z)))$, which is the second term.